# Reference resources from other module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have a main app module as well as a few library modules.

How can my Library module reference resources from the Main App module.

For instance:
My base app has a colors.xml which has a color item called "AppPrimary" which is blue.

In my library I want a view in an xml layout to reference @color/AppPrimary color, but that doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I should specify this isn't specifically appCompat resources. Just generic strings/colors/styles/in my main module. How can I reference them in the same project in my library module colors.xml/strings.xml?

Answer (score 16):

In your library module in the xml layout reference `?attr/colorPrimary` instead of `@color/AppPrimary`

This references the color palette attributes from your app's theme. i.e.;

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/AppPrimary</item>
```

You can also refer to the other color palette attributes like:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item> -> ?attr/colorPrimaryDark
<item name="colorAccent">...</item> -> ?attr/colorAccent
```

and so on.

[Please refer to this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette)

***CAVEAT***:
These examples refer the AppCompat implementation in the theme. i.e. no `android:` namespace prefix.

## -- EDIT --

The short answer is that you simply can't 'get' a defined color from your main module referenced to your libraries colors.xml file.

You can however leverage custom defined attributes in your theme to achieve the same effect.

This works by declaring a generic styleable in your `attrs.xml` file in the library module, Something like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="BaseTheme">
    <attr name="someColor" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

*Note: The name of the styleable has no bearing on this implementation so feel free to name it whatever you want.*

Then in your main module's theme definition in your 'style.xml' or 'theme.xml' file you'll want to set this attribute to the color you want to share, like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Color Palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">...</item>

    <!-- Here we define our custom attributes -->
    <item name="someColor">@color/dark_blue</item>

</style>
```

Once this is defined, you can reference the attribute in your library module XML code. e.g.;

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textColor="?attr/someColor"
    />
```

Comment: I should specify these aren't nessicarily appcompat resources. Say its just a general color defined in the main app module called "dark_blue". How do get that dark_blue color in my library colors.xml?

Comment: I have updated the answer to better suite your use case.

Comment: Thanks r0adkl I have changed the project structure. Instead I have defined a common core library which all modules (libraries and base app) can reference with app colors/common strings etc.

Comment: It works if external module has executable "thing" but what if I use external module as container for drawables?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how you can get color attributes while in a library module programmatically.

```
@ColorInt
public static int getAttributeColor(Context context, @AttrRes int colorAttribute)
{
    int[] attrs = {colorAttribute};
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    /*Get the color resourceID that we want (the first index, and only item, in the
    attrs array). Use ContextCompat to get the color according to the theme.
    */
    @ColorInt int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                                                 ta.getResourceId(0, -1));
    // ALWAYS call recycle() on the TypedArray when you’re done.
    ta.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Ex.

```
//Get the main applications ‘colorAccent' from the app’s color palette.
int appAccentColor = Utility.getMarketAttributeColor(context, R.attr.colorAccent);

//Get the color attribute your module made for the client app to define.
int moduleAttrColor = Utility.getMarketAttributeColor(context, R.attr.moduleColorAttr);
```

**Note**: This basic attribute retrieval process applies to *most* attribute types.